# Как найти определенный id перед искомым объектом

Tags: python, json

https://api.hh.ru/areas, тут содержатся id городов и поселков. Когда в программу в питоне заходит название города или поселка, как мне вытащить из json списка id этого объекта, который стоит перед его названием.

Comment: в каком виде заходит ? `Россия, Новая Кука` или `Новая Кука` или `Новая Кука, Россия` или двумя переменными `country, city` ... как вы получаете их от пользователя, короче говоря. И приведите вашу попытку это сделать

Comment: Без страны тупо город(Условно = "Великий Новгород"), а мои попыткы бред полный непомогут

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то можно так

```
import requests

areas = requests.get('https://api.hh.ru/areas')

for region in areas.json()[0]['areas']:
    for city in region['areas']:
        if city['name'] == 'Йошкар-Ола':
            print(city['name'])
            print(city['id'])
```

Вывод будет

```
Йошкар-Ола
61
```

Answer (score 0):

Рекурсивный обход коллекций поможет, который тут много раз обсуждался:

```py
import requests

def find(item, name):
    if not item:
        return
    if isinstance(item, list):
        for i in item:
            yield from find(i, name)   
        return
    if name.lower() in item['name'].lower():
        yield {'id': item['id'], 'name': item['name']}
    yield from find(item.get('areas'), name)

areas = requests.get('https://api.hh.ru/areas').json()
for d in find(areas, 'великий'):
    print(d)
```

Вывод:

```
{'id': '67', 'name': 'Великий Новгород'}
{'id': '1742', 'name': 'Великий Устюг'}
{'id': '3593', 'name': 'Великий Березный'}
{'id': '3111', 'name': 'Великий Бурлук'}
```

Тут я для примера возвращаю словарь из `id` и названия, чтобы во-первых проверить, что код работает, а во-вторых у меня используется поиск по подстроке, могущий дать несколько результатов. Вы можете возвращать только `id`, если хотите, или что угодно. И искать по точному совпадению. Главное сам алгоритм прохода по структуре у вас есть.